# Acceder a los metodos de una tabla y sus variables

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo 3 tablas: plantas, User y comentarios. La tabla de comentarios tiene claves foraneas que apuntan al user y al planta.
He creado una vista en la cual puedo ver que comentarios hay en cada planta:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Comentarios acerca del :nombre", ['nombre' => $plantas->nombre]) }} </h2>
        @forelse($comentario as $c)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-forum">
                <h3>
                    Usuario: {{$c->miembro}}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ $c->comentario }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre plantas en este momento") }}
        </div>
        @endforelse
        <a href="/flora/public" class="btn btn-info pull-right"> {{ __("Volver a la lista de plantas") }} </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

La variable c->miembro indica el id del usuario que escribio el comentario. Y necesito que en vez de un numero muestre el nombre del usuario (variable name).
La tabla Comentario tiene 2 funciones: vegetal(), que apunta a la planta, y usuario() que apunta a la tabla User.
Si por ejemplo, en vez de $c->miembro escribo $c->vegetal->nombre, en vez de mostrarse el id del usuario aparecera el nombre de la planta del comentario.
Sin embargo, me da error si intento poner $c->usuario->name:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho, pruebo a poner solo $c y me aparece datos del comentario y de la planta, pero no del usuario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PlantasController.php:

```
public function show(Plantas $plantas){
    $comentario = $plantas->comentarios()->with('vegetal')->paginate(5);
    return view('vegetal.detail', compact('plantas','comentario'));
    }
```

Comentario.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model{
    protected $table = 'comentarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'miembro', 'planta', 'comentario',
    ];

    public function vegetal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(plantas::class, 'planta');
    }

    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario');
    }
}
```

Sospecho que el fallo esta en la función show(), ya que aunque importo información sobre la tabla de las plantas, no he hecho lo mismo sobre la tabla User, pero no se como solucionarlo.

Edito: Debido a que modifique los valores de las tablas, pongo las migraciones.

Plantas:

```
class CreatePlantasTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('plantas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre'); // Nombre de la planta.
            $table->string('tamaño'); // Clasifica segun si es arbol, arbusto o hierba. 
            $table->string('flor'); // Si tiene o no flor.
            $table->string('hoja'); // Si es de hoja caduca o perenne.
            $table->text('descripcion'); // Caracteristicas del vegetal.
            $table->string('foto')->nullable(); // Esta variable sera utilizada para 
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('plantas');
    }
}
```

User:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comentario:

```
class CreateComentariosTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('comentarios', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('miembro'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('miembro')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('planta'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('planta')->references('id')->on('plantas');
            $table->text('comentario');
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('comentarios');
    }
}
```

Comment: Todo es muy confuso en tu código, ¿de dónde sale miembro? No veo nada así en las migraciones que pusiste en preguntas anteriores. Además, ¿por qué tendrías dos relaciones que apunten al mismo usuario y que aparentemente cumplen la misma función? Ten en cuenta que cuando escribes código, deberías hacerlo de forma que en el futuro (en unos 6 meses digamos) lo entiendas en menos de 10 segundos, y que las demás personas también lo puedan entender. Tu esquema de nombres no es consistente.

Comment: @Shaz Disculpa, es la variable usuario solo que le cambie el nombre para diferenciarlo de la función usuario() de la tabla Comentario. He editado mi mensaje para mostrar las migraciones actuales.

Comment: @Dev.Joel ¿Te refieres a use "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente sigo confundido por tu esquema de nombres, pero revisando tus migraciones, el error probablemente esté al definir de forma incorrecta la llave foránea de la relación One-To-Many en el modelo `User`:

```
public function comentarios()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class, 'miembro');
}
```

En Comentario:

```
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'miembro');
}
```

Así debería funcionar (siempre y cuando utilices los nombres de forma adecuada):

```
{{ $c->miembro->name }}
```

Comment: Si, veo que como he llamado los nombres de mis tablas te es confuso, pero así es como las cree en su momento. ¿Como las renombro ahora?

Comment: Aparte, ya conseguido que el programa funcione, lo unico que lo que yo he escrito es "$c->usuario->name".